# How to add null value for null key into array php?

Tags: php, arrays

How to add `$a[null]` without `uasort`?

my code is

```
$a = array(3=>'fff',4=>'sss');
end($a);
$key = key($a);
for($i=0;$i<=($key);$i++){
    if(!isset($a[$i])){$a[$i]=null;}
}
```

**i want this**

`([0] => null [1] => null ...... [3] => fff [4] => sss )`

thank you

Comment: You can't have null keys; array keys must be either an integer or a string value: do you mean a null value?

Comment: `$keys = max(array_keys($a));
$a = array_merge(array_fill(0, $keys-1, null), $a);`

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: While `array_merge()` and `$keys-1` from Mark's commented solution works for the OP's sample input, if key `3` is changed to `2`, then the output is not as expected.  In `array_fill()` the 2nd parameter is the number of elements to generate -- `$keys-1` makes `[0], [1], and [2]` so it works with the sample input.  When there is no `$a[3]` `$key-1` will not produce it -- making the suggestion unreliable.  Also, `array_merge()` does not preserve keys. [Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2ac7f96c8f70fa94bfde245088f6793ddaf7103b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one-liner that uses the last key in the `$a` array:

Code:

```
var_export(array_replace(array_fill(0,key(array_slice($a,-1,null,true)),null),$a));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => NULL,
  1 => NULL,
  2 => NULL,
  3 => 'fff',
  4 => 'sss',
)
```

This will generate a default array using `array_fill()` and the last key in the `$a` array. `[0=>NULL,1=>NULL,2=>NULL,3=>NULL]` (we know that index `4` already has a value, so we don't need to go any farther).

Then just use `array_replace()` to overwrite the null elements where an element exists in `$a`.

Here is a slightly improved version: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f7a4021abc10e773b782fb026b8a3418f0e8704d))

```
var_export(array_replace(array_fill(0,max(array_keys($a)),null),$a));
```

This will seek out the "highest" (not merely the last key) and perform the same task.  This is handy if your `$a` keys are not already in order.

Or if you want to see a loop version:

```
$max=max(array_keys($a));
for($i=0; $i<=$max; ++$i){
    $result[]=isset($a[$i])?$a[$i]:null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = [
    3 => 'fff',
    4 => 'sss'
];

$nulls = array_fill(0, max(array_keys($data)), null);
$out   = array_replace($nulls, $data);

var_dump($out);
```

Output:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => null
  1 => null
  2 => null
  3 => string 'fff' (length=3)
  4 => string 'sss' (length=3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code you needed

```
<?php
$a = array(3=>'fff',4=>'sss');
$new_array = [];
end($a);
$key = key($a);
for($i=0;$i<=($key);$i++){
    if(!isset($a[$i])){ $new_array[] = null; }
    else $new_array[] = $a[$i];
}
$a = $new_array;
var_dump($a);
?>
```

This gives

```
  0 => null
  1 => null
  2 => null
  3 => string 'fff'
  4 => string 'sss'
```